# Handle drag and drop between two CollectionviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uicollectionviewcell

How to handle drag and drop between two collection-view cell. we also have cell reorder functionality(implemented).

What exactly we need is: drag cell's subview (UILabel) and drop it to another cell

[image]

Comment: see this for help : https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-drag-drop-uicollectionview-cells-by-utilizing-dropdelegate-and-dragdelegate-6e3512327202

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, but we all-ready have that functionality. what now we need is add support to drag cell's subview (Label) and drop into another cell

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Add long press gesture to cell label.
2. On tap begin you hide the source label and create a snapshot of the label.
3. then drag it to the destination cell, get the index path from the location of the touchpoints.
4. On ending the gesture, add the label text to the destination cell label, and remove the snapshot.

I think this will work. I had not tried this before, but I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : First You need to set drag and drop delegate like as below

```
collectionView1.dragDelegate = self

collectionView2.dropDelegate = self
```

Step 2 : You need to add which item to drag in itemsForBeginning delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
{
        let item = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item as NSString) //Here For your use case you can add label for drag
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
}
```

Step 3 : You need to add performDropWith delegate method to drop item for collectionView2

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)
{
    let destinationIndexPath : IndexPath
    if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath
    {
        destinationIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    else
    {
        let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(item: row - 1, section: 0)
    }
    if coordinator.proposal.operation == .copy
    {
        //Here you can add your copy code
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work I think. As this will drag and drop the cell. But he wants the cell subview to be dragged and dropped.